# Hosting multiple node.js instances on nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, web, proxypass

Hey guys I have a Rasberry Pi 4 and I wish to host multiple node.js websites using Nginx, right now I have one instance that runs well and is connected to Cloudflare.

Current 'default' file below

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5085;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Now I need to host 2 more websites here, those are -
*example1.com which runs on localhost:3000* &
*example2.com which runs on localhost:4000*

Now after this, I got another doubt, I need to add these 2 to Cloudflare.
[image: Cloudflare DNS for my current website]

In image one, I just had to put my public IP Address which was port forwarding at port 80
here's an image for that
[image: current port forward setting]

Now how would I connect the host to cloudflare. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to copy your current nginx server configuration and change the server_name property to `server_name  example2.com` and change the `proxy_pass` target accordingly.

It will look like something like this :

```
# example.com server/proxy
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;

   server_name example.com www.example.com;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:5085;
       # ...
   }
}

# example2.com server/proxy
server {
   listen 80;       # we removed the default_server tag here   
   listen [::]:80;  # because it can only be used once  

   server_name example2.com www.example2.com;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
       # ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! but, how would I add it to Cloudflare?

Comment: What would I add as content in cloudflare DNS

Comment: The same as the first domain for the second one

Comment: Thanks, I got it working! I'll make a video on this topic soon!